# NodeJS Event Loops & Listening for Events

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have a door sensor attached to a Raspberry Pi. To check if the door has been opened, the below script runs on a 2 second interval. If it has been opened, a POST request will be made to an external API server.

This works great, but the goal is to make a POST request containing the information of **how long** the door was opened for and **when** it was opened. My first thought was to use Node Events & EventEmitter capabilities but I'm unsure on the implementation of this.

```
var rest = require('restler');
var gpio = require('pi-gpio');

setInterval(function(){
  gpio.read(16, function(err, value) { // sensor is attached to pin 16
    if(err) throw err;
    if(value === 1){ // If closed, the value is 0
      console.log("Door Opened");
      rest.post('http://192.168.6.109:3000/door/save', {
              data: {
                door: 'Open'
              }
      }).on('complete', function(data, response){
          console.log('door status code: ' + response.statusCode);
      });
    }
  });
},2000);
```

Comment: Just save what you need and send it? Or log the changes in the server?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean 'save what you need'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 things: the timestamp and the elapsed time between open and close events. Then you can send the information to the server. Something like this could work:

```
var rest = require('restler');
var gpio = require('pi-gpio');

var open;

setInterval(function(){
    gpio.read(16, function(err, value) { // sensor is attached to pin 
        if(err) throw err;
        if(value == '1'){ // If closed, the value is '0'
            console.log("Door Opened");
            open = Date.now ();
        }else{
            //"0" is assumed
            console.log("Door Closed");

            //Check whether the door was opened
            if (open){
                var elapsed = Date.now () - open;

                rest.post('http://192.168.6.109:3000/door/save', {
                    data: {
                        door: 'Open',
                        openTime: open,
                        elapsedTime: elapsed
                    }
                }).on('complete', function(data, response){
                        console.log('door status code: ' + response.statusCode);
                });

                open = null;
            }
        }
    });
},2000);
```

But I'm afraid that the elapsed time will be always a multiple of 2000. Try to decrease the interval time.

Comment: Got this to work once I included `if(typeof open === 'undefined'){open = Date.now ();}` in the instantiation of the `open` variable, which prevented it from getting reset every time the code looped